# What is the return value of a recursive call

Tags: java, recursion

```
java version "1.8.0_92"
```

I have the following code I am trying to understand and trace.

The part I don't understand is the `* a` at the end. When does that multiplication get called? And what is the return value of `power1(a, n - 1);`

Is it `n - 1 * a`

```
 public static double power1(double a, int n) {
        double result;
        if(n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            result = power1(a, n - 1) * a;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try writing it out on paper. The return value will depend on the arguments passed to that method.

Comment: If you write it out like @LoganKulinski says, you'll find that it's `double (from the recursive call) * double a`, so that mean you get a double back, which is exactly as the method power1 defines.

Comment: As far as when it gets called: The program will first check if n == 0, obviously not. Then it's gonna calculate the result. For the result it needs: 1) power1 en 2) a. Time to calc power1. Start power1(a,n-1). Restart with checking if 0. At some point your n - k will be zero. When k = n. So it gives back a 1. Then it jumps back to when your n - k was at 1. It now known power(a, n-k) ==> 1 * a; It returns a. Then back to when it knows  power(a,n-k+1). It does a*a. One from recursion and 1 from an actual parameter. Etc, until it has done all the steps needed to calc power(a,n-1) * a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the code to print a trace of the recursion. That can help you understand what is going on.

```
/**
 * Print string form of `o`, but indented with n spaces
 */
private static void printIndented(int n, Object o) {
    while (n-->0) System.out.print("  ");
    System.out.println(o);
}

/* 
 * Added a third param `d` to keep track of the depth of the recursion
 */
public static double power1(double a, int n, int d) {
    // Entering a "possible" recursive call
    printIndented(d, "call power1, a=" + a + ", n=" + n + ", d=" + d);

    double result;
    if(n == 0) {
        // Returning from the base case, this should have the largest depth.
        printIndented(d, "return 1.0");

        return 1;
    }
    else {
        result = power1(a, n - 1, d + 1);

        // Return from intermediate recursive calls, we print
        // the value of power1(a, n-1) as well.
        printIndented(d, "return " + result + " * " + a);
        return result * a;
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println(power1(1.4, 3, 0));
}
```

**Output**

```
call power1, a=1.4, n=3, d=0
  call power1, a=1.4, n=2, d=1
    call power1, a=1.4, n=1, d=2
      call power1, a=1.4, n=0, d=3
      return 1.0
    return 1.0 * 1.4
  return 1.4 * 1.4
return 1.9599999999999997 * 1.4
2.7439999999999993
```

As you can see, the value from the inner return becomes the `result` in the outer return statement.

Answer (score 3):

## Return value of power1(a,n-1)

We can see that power1 is defined as `public static _double_ power1(double a, int n)` This means that on the line

`result = power1(a, n - 1) * a;`

the type will be :

`double = double * double;`

## When the multiplication gets called

We start our function with `n` and `a`. `a` will be constant in this implementation. It's given straight as to the next recursive call.

Yet `n` varies.

We call `power1(a,n)`. It checks first if n == 0; It is not.
So we go to the else part of the if. Time to calculate `result`.

To know what the value of `result` is, we need power1(a,n-1). We proceed. n-1 can be 0 or can not be.

If it's 0, we return 1, and we now know that power1(a,n-1) = 1. We can now multiply it with a.

If it's not 0, then we need a new result, seeing as we're in a completely seperate call of the `power1` method. We now need power1(a,n-2). We check again for 0. If n-2 == 0, return 1 to get the caller to calculate power(a,n-1). If not go down another call, now with n-3... Etc

#### In terms of the timing of calling the multiplication.

It's gonna call all the (n) recursive calls first, before doing n multiplications.

Answer (score 2):

If you call power1 with `a = 2` and `n = 3`, this is what will happen:

`result = power1(2, 2) * 2;`
`power1(2, 2) = power1(2, 1) * 2;`
`power1(2, 1) = power1(2, 0) * 2;`
`power1(2, 0) = 1`

In the above example, the `* a` happens three times in total. It is called whenever power1(a, n) returns a value. The first `power1(a, n)` to return a value will be `power1(2, 0)` (this is because `n = 0` is your "base" case). Then `power1(2, 1)` will return 2. Then `power1(2, 2)` will return 4. Then your initial call to `power1(2, 3)` will return 8.

Answer (score 0):

First you call power (a,n-1) until n == 0 which is your base case .

Then the 1 gets returned and is multiplied by the value of a. 
Then a is returned  to the previous call where it is multiplied by a . The process is repeated N times and thus you get A^n. I would recommend you go throught one example of this code giving it some initials values and tracing the code using pen and paper.

Comment: You probably meant to say n-k == 0. The if checks for the n value to be 0, and the depth of recursion is variable.

Comment: Rafael. Try to proof your answers before posting them.  You are writing for the community at large.

Comment: The whole point of this cumunity is to find mistakes in others code .